# Please can anyone tell me how to use Keywords with Boolean Operators in SpanTermQuery in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to find the number of occerrences of the keyword "(Mercedes OR Benz)" with the use of SpanTermQuery , but it only uses single words in small cases like "mercedes", "benz" , etc. So i'm not able to find the occurrences of the keyword "Mercedes OR Benz".

Please help me if anyone has any idea about this.

Following is the code snippet i'm using.

```
SpanQuery spanQuery = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("FullText","Mercedes OR Benz"));
// define your span query here
Spans spans = spanQuery.getSpans(indexReader);
int occurrenceCount = 0;
while (spans.next()) {
   occurrenceCount++;
}
System.out.println("Number of Occurences in FullText spans : "+occurrenceCount);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MultiFieldQueryParser

```
String querystr = "Mercedes OR Benz" ;
String fields[] = {"brands"};

StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
Query q = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, fields, analyzer).parse(querystr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i dont want to search in multiple fields i want to find the number of occurrences of the keyword in a particular document. But problem is SpanTermQuery doesn't allow use of boolean operators or special characters in the keywords.